# Backbone View events won't fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-events

I am using Backbone in a project and I am trying to get the events functionality of Backbone Views to work correctly. I have the following code (it is extracted out of my current application):

My Base File:

```
window.App =
   Models: {}
   Views: {}
```

My Model:

```
class App.Models.Story extends Backbone.Model
  defaults:
    id: null
    content: null
```

My View:

```
class App.Views.Story extends Backbone.View
  tagName: "li"
  className : "story item"

  events:
    "click" : "test"

  test: ->
    alert "TEST"

  render: ->
    html = "<div> #{@model.get("content")} </div>"
    $(@el).html(html)
    return this
```

The Code on page load:

```
$(document).ready ->
  story = new App.Models.Story(content: "Some content")
  view = new App.Views.Story(model: story)
  $("body").append(view.render().el)
```

The element renders but when I click on it, the click handler does not execute. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: -1, for not telling how you fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to hate this answer...  you need to declare `events` not `event`:

```
events:
    "click" : "test"
```

Comment: Good catch! Changing it does not fix my problem however. I am changing the question to reflect this.

Comment: @ZameerManji Really surprised about that.  I put your code into a jsFiddle and it just worked once I changed it.

Comment: Care to explain what you did to get it to work?  It may help others who stumble upon this question/answer

Comment: @Zameer I think you should definitely tell us what you did to fix it, I am having the same problem now.